# Polymorphism and Inheritance in C++

Tags: java, object, c++-cli

So in java I had the following implementation:

```
public abstract class PFigure implements Comparable
```

and the java implementation for my inheritance and polymorphism:

```
public class PFigureList
{
   private final int MAX_VEHICLES = 9;
   private PFigure list[] = new PFigure[MAX_VEHICLES];
   private int count = 0;

   /**
   Adds a PFigure to the list if the list is not full and increments the count.

   @param myFig The "vehicle" PFigure that is going to be added to the list
   */
   public void add(PFigure myFig)
   {
      if(count <= 9)
         list[count++] = myFig;
   }
/**
   For every figure in the list, it calls their hide() function, their 
   polymorphic move() function, and then their draw() function to show where 
   they are now.
   */
   public void move()
   {
      for(int i = 1; i < count; i++)
      {
         list[i].hide();
         list[i].move();
         list[i].draw();
      }
   }
```

Now what I want to accomplish is this except very similar to it in C++. Here is my code:

```
void VBotList::Add(VBot * add)
{
   vbot[count++] = add;
}

void VBotList::Move()
{
   /*for(int i = 0; i < list.GetCount(); i++)
      list.GetValue(i)->Move();*/

   for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      vbot[i]->Move();
}

class VBotList
{
   private:
     int count;

     VBot * vbot[50];

   public:
      VBotList() : count(0){ }
      void Add(VBot * vbot);
      void Move();
      void Show();

};

public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }
  static VBotList * list = new VBotList();
```

And my attempt to implement it:

```
   private: System::Void speedTimer_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
               list->Move();
               Invalidate();
               speedTimer->Interval = speedTrackBar->Value;
            }
private: System::Void vbotAddButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            if(comboBox1->SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
               VBot * x = new BillyBot(System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox1->Text), System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox2->Text), panel1);
               list->Add(x);
            }
         }
private: System::Void panel1_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) {
            list->Show();
         }
```

My goal here was to take a VBot object which is stored in a VBotList, which was like my PFigureList of PFigure objects in java. I have no clue why, but I cannot get it to actually display my object on the panel. I had to make the initialization of the VBotList static in order for it to not give me error messages. Am I missing something completely obvious or am I just doing something incorrect about displaying the object? Any hints, advice, or a slap on the hand about my code would be great.

Show() Basically just displays the image. I'll post the code if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You work in C++/CLI, so you're class must be managed too, example :

```
ref class Bot
{
public:
    Bot()
    {

    }
};

ref class VBotList
{
private:
    int m_count;
    array<Bot ^> ^vbot;
public:
    VBotList() : m_count(0), vbot(gcnew array<Bot ^>(50))
    {
    }
    void Add(Bot ^newBot)
    {
        vbot[m_count++] = newBot;
    }
    int getCount()
    {
        return m_count;
    }
};
```

And next :

```
private:
    VBotList ^list;

public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list = gcnew VBotList();
    label1->Text = System::Convert::ToString(list->getCount());
    }

// ...
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    Bot ^bot = gcnew Bot();
    list->Add(bot);
    label1->Text = System::Convert::ToString(list->getCount());
}
```

^ declare a handle to a managed pointer.